# Having trouble creating a dancing planet pattern

Tags: c++

Hey guys I am having trouble creating a pattern that is called the invisible dance of the planets. This pattern is done by drawing a line in between two different planets and is shown by this [animation](https://www.sciencealert.com/the-celestial-dance-between-earth-and-venus-draws-a-stunning-pattern-through-space). The issue I'm having is with the for loop of drawing the lines, I got all the positions of the planets done depending on their number of years to rotate. Another factor to include is the change in color when a new year is cycled. The issue I'm having is the final image of the svg file. [My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF8bx.png) [Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThZYC.png)

```
int main() 
 {
 int dim = 1000;
 int planet1DayRotate = 687;
 int planet2DayRotate = 365;
 int planet1Distance = 187;  //in million km
 int planet2Distance = 150; // in million km
 double anglep1 = 0; 
 double anglep2 = 0;
 int years = 2;
 double cx = dim/2;
 double cy = dim/2;
 double angleIncrementP1 = (2*M_PI)/planet1DayRotate;
 double angleIncrementP2 = (2*M_PI)/planet2DayRotate;
double totalDays = years * planet1DayRotate;
int indexP1 = 1;
int indexP2 = 1;
int indexColor = 1;
double planet1x[planet1DayRotate];
double planet1y[planet1DayRotate];
double planet2x[planet2DayRotate];
double planet2y[planet2DayRotate];

startSVG(1000, 1000);
rectangle(0,0, dim, dim, "black");

cout << "totalDays: " << totalDays << endl << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
{
  planet2x[indexP2-1] = cx + planet2Distance * cos(anglep2);
  planet2y[indexP2-1] = cy + planet2Distance * sin(anglep2);
  planet1x[indexP1-1] = cx + planet1Distance * cos(anglep1);
  planet1y[indexP1-1] = cy + planet1Distance * sin(anglep1);

  anglep2 += angleIncrementP2;
  anglep1 += angleIncrementP1;
  if(i > planet2DayRotate)
  {

    line(planet1x[indexP1-1],planet1y[indexP2-1],planet2x[indexP2-1],planet2y[indexP2-1],"yellow", 1);
  } 

  line(planet1x[indexP1-1],planet1y[indexP1-1]-1,planet2x[indexP2-1],planet2y[indexP2-1],"white", 1);
  //makes sure the index is within bounds of the arrays
  indexP1 = (indexP1 - 1) % planet1DayRotate + 1;
  indexP2 = (indexP2 - 1) % planet2DayRotate + 1;
} 
endSVG();
}
```

Comment: You said *where* you think the issue is, but you forgot to say *what* it is. (And please remove irrelevant commented-out code.)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I edited out most of the useless comments and showed a picture of the results I'm getting from my code.

Comment: Can you explain what the expected output is, and what output you are getting?

Comment: I included an image of the output I'm getting, and the hyperlink to the animation is the expected output, I can add a screenshot of the expected as well if that helps.

Comment: The expected result does not draw a line for every day of the `planet1` rotation, there seem to be about 100 points that are visited multiple times. Judging from the expected result and the numbers used, you should do 8 rotations of `planet1` (and get about 15 rotations of `planet2`) before the pattern repeats. The example in your first link uses a different relation (about 13 rotations of `planet2` for every 8 rotations of `planet1`) which will result in a different pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included a JavaScript version of your code to make it easier for readers to see what is going on and be able to play with it.

```js
var my_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = my_canvas.getContext("2d");

function rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, color) {
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

function line(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width) {
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.lineWidth = width;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1, y1);
  context.lineTo(x2, y2);
  context.stroke();
}

let dim = 1000;
let planet1DayRotate = 687;
let planet2DayRotate = 365;
let planet1Distance = 187; //in million km
let planet2Distance = 150; // in million km
let anglep1 = 0;
let anglep2 = 0;
let years = 2;
let cx = dim / 2;
let cy = dim / 2;
let angleIncrementP1 = (2 * Math.PI) / planet1DayRotate;
let angleIncrementP2 = (2 * Math.PI) / planet2DayRotate;
let totalDays = years * planet1DayRotate;
let indexP1 = 1;
let indexP2 = 1;
let indexColor = 1;
let planet1x = new Array(planet1DayRotate);
let planet1y = new Array(planet1DayRotate);
let planet2x = new Array(planet2DayRotate);
let planet2y = new Array(planet2DayRotate);

rectangle(0, 0, dim, dim, "#000");

console.log("totalDays: " + totalDays);
for (var i = 0; i < totalDays; i++) {
  planet2x[indexP2 - 1] = cx + planet2Distance * Math.cos(anglep2);
  planet2y[indexP2 - 1] = cy + planet2Distance * Math.sin(anglep2);
  planet1x[indexP1 - 1] = cx + planet1Distance * Math.cos(anglep1);
  planet1y[indexP1 - 1] = cy + planet1Distance * Math.sin(anglep1);

  anglep2 += angleIncrementP2;
  anglep1 += angleIncrementP1;
  if (i > planet2DayRotate) {
    line(planet1x[indexP1 - 1], planet1y[indexP2 - 1], planet2x[indexP2 - 1], planet2y[indexP2 - 1], "#FF0", 1);
  }

  line(planet1x[indexP1 - 1], planet1y[indexP1 - 1] - 1, planet2x[indexP2 - 1], planet2y[indexP2 - 1], "#FFF", 1);
  //makes sure the index is within bounds of the arrays
  indexP1 = (indexP1 - 1) % planet1DayRotate + 1;
  indexP2 = (indexP2 - 1) % planet2DayRotate + 1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000">
  This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

The original code draws a line for each day of `planet1`s orbit. In your expected result, it looks like there are about 100 points in `planet1`s orbit that are used to draw the lines.

The original code used orbits for Mars and Earth, while the expected result uses orbits for Earth and Venus. For every 8 Mars orbits, about 15,05 Earth orbits happen. For every 8 Earth orbits, about 12,97 Venus orbits happen. The resulting pattern will differ from the expected result because of this.

Storing intermediate values in an array which are used exactly once, seems like a waste of time.

So: if you do 8 "rotations" of `planet1` and draw a line from every 100th position in `planet1` "rotation", you get this:

```js
var my_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = my_canvas.getContext("2d");

function rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, color) {
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

function line(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width) {
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.lineWidth = width;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1, y1);
  context.lineTo(x2, y2);
  context.stroke();
}

let dim = 1000;
let planet1DayRotate = 687;
let planet2DayRotate = 365;
let planet1Distance = 187; //in million km
let planet2Distance = 150; // in million km
let anglep1 = 0;
let anglep2 = 0;
let cx = dim / 2;
let cy = dim / 2;
let stepsEachYear = 100;
let totalSteps = 8 * stepsEachYear;
let stepPercentage = planet1DayRotate / stepsEachYear;
let angleIncrementP1 = ((2 * Math.PI) / planet1DayRotate) * stepPercentage;
let angleIncrementP2 = ((2 * Math.PI) / planet2DayRotate) * stepPercentage;

rectangle(0, 0, dim, dim, "#000");

for (let i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) {
  planet2x = cx + planet2Distance * Math.cos(anglep2);
  planet2y = cy + planet2Distance * Math.sin(anglep2);
  planet1x = cx + planet1Distance * Math.cos(anglep1);
  planet1y = cy + planet1Distance * Math.sin(anglep1);

  anglep2 += angleIncrementP2;
  anglep1 += angleIncrementP1;
  line(planet1x, planet1y, planet2x, planet2y, "#FFF", 1);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000">
  This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

```cpp
int main() 
{
    int dim = 1000;
    int planet1DayRotate = 687;
    int planet2DayRotate = 365;
    int planet1Distance = 187; // in million km
    int planet2Distance = 150; // in million km
    double anglep1 = 0; 
    double anglep2 = 0;
    int years = 2;
    double cx = dim/2;
    double cy = dim/2;
    int stepsEachYear = 100;
    int totalSteps = 8 * stepsEachYear;
    double stepPercentage = planet1DayRotate/stepsEachYear;
    double angleIncrementP1 = ((2*M_PI)/planet1DayRotate)*stepPercentage;
    double angleIncrementP2 = ((2*M_PI)/planet2DayRotate)*stepPercentage;

    startSVG(1000, 1000);
    rectangle(0,0, dim, dim, "black");

    for(int i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++)
    {
        double planet2x = cx + planet2Distance * cos(anglep2);
        double planet2y = cy + planet2Distance * sin(anglep2);
        double planet1x = cx + planet1Distance * cos(anglep1);
        double planet1y = cy + planet1Distance * sin(anglep1);

        anglep2 += angleIncrementP2;
        anglep1 += angleIncrementP1;
        line(planet1x,planet1y,planet2x,planet2y,"white", 1);
    } 
    endSVG();
}
```

[image: Result of javascript code]

Comment: Thanks for the help, the reason I had from earth to mars was that the code needs to work for any two planets but this is a very helpful ground level on where I was messing up. The reason I had arrays inside of the loop was that my professor said it was necessary, probably because he wants us to make sure we can use them